# Are there potential issues with using Apache CXF for mobile applications?

Tags: web-services, mobile, cxf

We'll be developing mobile applications (for both iOS and Android platforms) that will be using web services. I'll be the one implementing the web services part and I plan on using Apache CXF.

It would be the first time I'm using CXF but I'm highly considering it because of its integration with Spring.

What are the potential issues (if any) with using CXF for mobile apps? If there are, is there supposed to be a better alternative to CXF? If there are none, any best practices I should also be considering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've been through the mobile ringer... WAP, J2ME, Brew, embedded languages, etc. Mobile development is exciting and also a bit scary...

Spring Integration: There is a big difference between * and **... be careful when setting up filters. It's easy to get out of hand securing end-points.

Authentication: How will your mobile devices authenticate and what is their role in Authentication, Authorization, and Access? Session management on occasionally connected devices - can get interesting. If a session goes stale how are you going to handle challenge / response?

App Security: Does your solution require SSL? Managing self-signed certificates is painful and time consuming. Do yourself and your mobile devs a favor and get a CA certificate in place up-front. You will save time (money) and a great deal of headache.

Proxy Power: Ideally, the people writing the front-end should be using an IDE that supports some kind of tethering for realtime debugging. Being able to add a breakpoint and introspect what's going on in the code... is mint. However, I haven't seen an IDE yet that gives front-end mobile devs the same experience as back-end devs. My guess is that your mobile devs are going all goo-goo eyes over jQuery. Understandably so! WebStorm and Aptana are good in the JS arena - but they're still evolving.

This is a problem front-end mobile devs need to work out... right? Yes... and no. Without proper tools everyone in the dev-chain will have to cook-up their own ways of answering questions like:

- What did the mobile app send?
- Was the request formed correctly?
- What was the response?

Again, save yourself some time and finger-pointing and just sit down together (front and back-end devs) and work out a tech-stack that provides everyone optimal access to all app communications. Configurable logging on the server is a good idea to have in place from inception. Are you familiar with Firebug or Charles Proxy? A proxy can greatly simplify the debugging equation - just sayin'

Exceptions: Oh... and beware HTTP response codes. Exceptions on the server-side should be gracefully handled to prevent mobile consumers from choking on responses. Yikes - that's all I can say is YIKES!

Service / Life Cycle: Have you calculated the duration of the service and / or life cycle of your application? Knowing this can greatly impact architectural decisions.

Web Services: My knee-jerk reaction - is this the best technology for your product? Why Web Services? Can you come up with three concrete reasons why WS is the best option? From my experience, the most compact protocol will usually lead to the best user experience.

Food for thought... ASP.NET and JSon make a good pair.
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

SOAP-XML is cumbersome.  :-(
http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/

Have you considered RESTful Web Services? If you're using CXF... there are three different ways to build RESTful Web Services.

JAX-RS (CXF has an implementation of JSR-311 baked-in)
  JAX-WS (more complicated - meh)
  HTTP Binding (deprecated... may be removed from CXF in the future - fair warning)

More at: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/restful-services.html
Examples: http://solutionsfit.com/blog/2010/04/21/enterprise-mashups-with-restful-web-services-and-jquery-part-1/

Alternatives: There are so many great projects out there... Axis2 and Shiro come to mind. Without knowing more about your solution - it's difficult to recommend anything.

Final Thoughts: As a back-end dev, I would recommend getting familiar with the entire app tech stack and kick-off development with a series of small but functional samples that light the way through the obstacles mentioned above. Hold-on to the samples! They may prove useful in zeroing in on regression.

Mobile devices are getting faster and faster every day... it's true, but any dev worth their salt will know that they need to code to a common denominator if they want a mobile product to be widely consumed, adopted, and embraced.